# module pattern setters that has methods

Tags: javascript

### EDIT:

Everything is working as I expected. It was just an error calling the template method. I mistyped a () so I was trying template.method instead of template().method;

Anyway, if somebody would like to explain me if this is a valid design pattern or if I should go in a different way I will be definitively very grateful.

---

I read about the module pattern and I'm trying to implement it in some of my projects. The problem is that, in my opinion, I'm twisting it too much.
I'm inspired by the google apps script style where many objects returns other objects with methods and so on and they pass arguments.

something like

```
object.method(var).otherMethod();
```

What I want to achieve is a method that receives a parameter, sets an internal variable to that parameter and then returns an object with methods that uses that variable. Here is a minified version of the code that does not work:

```
var H_UI =(function (window) { 

var selectedTemplate,
    compileTemplate = function(){},
    parseTemplateFields = function(){};

//template subModule. Collect: collects the template fields and returns a JSON representation.
 var template = function(templateString){ 
     if(templateString) selectedTemplate = templateString;
         return {
                getHtml:function(){  return compileTemplate(  parseTemplateFields(  selectedTemplate  )  ) } , 
                collect:function(){ 
                 .. operating over selectedTemplate ...
                return JSON.stringify(result)}

                } };
return {

    template:template

  };

})(window);
```

<strike>If I remove the line :</strike>

```
if(templateString) selectedTemplate = templateString;
```

and replace selectedTemplate with the parameter templateString in the methods of the returned object it works as expected. I know that I cant create a set() method in the returned object and use it like this

```
H_UI.template().set(var)
```

But I find it ugly. Anyway I think that I'm messing things up.
What is the best way to construct this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `H_UI.template()` creates a new object every time you call `template()` on it, your solution does not work. Because the variable `selectedTemplate` is created only once when the immediate function is called.

However if your intent is this your solution works fine. (variable `selectedTemplate` is shared for all calls to `template()`).

But if you want to every call to `template` creates a new object. Please tell me to write my idea

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a valid design pattern or if I should go in a different way

Yes, enabling chaining is definitely a valid design pattern.

However, if your `template()` method returns a new object, that object and its methods should only depend on itself (including the local variables and parameters of the `template` call), but not on anything else like the parent object that `template` was called on.

So either remove that "global" `selectedTemplate` thing:

```
var H_UI = (function () { 

    function compileTemplate(){}
    function parseTemplateFields(){}

    // make a template
    function template(templateString) {
        return {
            getHtml: function(){
                return compileTemplate(parseTemplateFields(templateString));
            }, 
            collect: function(){ 
                // .. operating over templateString ...
                return JSON.stringify(result)
            }
         }
    }
    return {template:template};
})();
```

or make only one module with with a global `selectedTemplate`, a setter for it, and global methods:

```
var H_UI = (function () { 

    var selectedTemplate;

    function compileTemplate(){}
    function parseTemplateFields(){}
    return {
        template: function(templateString){ 
             if (templateString)
                 selectedTemplate = templateString;
             return this; // for chaining
        },
        getHtml: function(){
            return compileTemplate(parseTemplateFields(selectedTemplate));
        }, 
        collect: function(){ 
            // .. operating over selectedTemplate ...
            return JSON.stringify(result)}
        }
    };
})();
```

The difference is striking when we make two templates with that method:

```
var templ1 = H_UI.template("a"),
    templ2 = H_UI.template("b");
```

What would you expect them to do? In a functional design, `templ1` must not use `"b"`. With the first snippet we have this, and `templ1 != templ2`. However, if `.template()` is a mere setter, and every call affects the whole instance (like in the second snippet), we have `templ1 == H_UI` and `templ2 == H_UI`.

Comment: Hello Bergi. Thank you very much for your very clear explanation. I think I will stick to the second solution. Currently what I have is a bad mix of both. What I was trying to do is to group together all the calls related to template. I don't want to permit H_UI.getHtml, just H_UI.template().getHtml() .  Probably I'm mixing concepts again. Thank you!